# WebService always returning null craftyclicks

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to get an xml repoonse from a third party provider for post code lookup craftyclicks.co.uk. I have tried the following code but I am not getting the xml return stream yet when i type the url in the browser it works fine.

Post Code is in format of BT399XX
response=data_formatted

```
public XmlTextReader readXML(string postcode, string response, string accessCode)   {            
 XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("http://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/xml/rapidaddress?postcode=" + postcode + "&response=" + response + "&key=" + accessCode);
        return textReader;
    }
```

But when I check the value of text reader it is always Null :-(

Comment: Some sites are "crafty" and validate that some header information exists in your requests.  When you initiate requests from a browser, these headers are filled in automatically for you.  I suggest using your favorite browser, opening the "developer tools", sending the request, and investigating the headers that are being sent.  I've done a bit of web scraping in my day and I have had to make my automated requests look more like web requests.

Comment: @jensendp when i loko at the data through developer tools it does return valid xml that is what stranged and when i test it through their form online it does indead return the valid address for my area that i no off to insure it works

Comment: In the developer tools look at the Request headers that are being sent.  There is a good chance that your site is looking for User-Agent to be sent up or something.